# PHP 101: variable vs function

Tags: php, performance

I'm creating a global file to hold items that will be re-used throughout my website. What are the differences between these two lines of code? Is one "better" than the other?

This:

```
$logo = "img/mainlogo.jpg";
```

vs this:

```
function logo() {
   echo "img/mainlogo.jpg";
}
```

Comment: actually you save some bytes in the ram if you dont use a variable

Comment: i think second one is better

Comment: i'd change echo to return, but personally i like storing configuration together in an array or some object rather than having a separate variable for it

Comment: Why do you think the second is better?

Comment: Apples and oranges, they are not equivalent.

Comment: `+1` for a good question! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Functions are good.

I see that `function logo()` is better than `$logo`. `echo` doesn't take much memory, but `$logo` does. Even though, `function logo()` takes something, it will be handled by PHP's very own garbage collector. You can also use these functions to ensure that you are not misusing the memory allocated.

1. `memory_get_peak_usage();`
2. `memory_get_usage();`

#### Explanation:

> Upon the ending of an in use function PHP clears the memory it was using, at least more efficiently than if not using a function. If you are using recursive code or something similar that is memory intensive try putting the code into a function or method, upon closing of the function/method the memory used for the function will be garbaged much more efficiently than that of unsetting variables within the loop itself.

**Source:** [7 tips to prevent PHP running out of memory](http://v1.srcnix.com/2010/02/10/7-tips-to-prevent-php-running-out-of-memory/)

Comment: -1, that article is full of edge cases, blatantly silly practices and micromanagement.  It is *not* a good resource and should not be used as an authoritative source.

Comment: @Charles I took the explanation from there, okay? It is no way related to what I said. For the sake of (no plagiarism), I gave the link. If you want, I can remove it. Removing the downvote?

Comment: but it sounds like there's nothing WRONG with using a function over a variable, even if it can be seen as micromanagement.

Comment: Yeah, have been in the PHP Server Admin for years, so my suggestion would be good. :)

Comment: So you're saying that (i) a function body does not take any memory (ii) invoking a function does not use any stack space.

Comment: @SalmanA Compared to having a variable, yeah, when the function just uses `echo`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/YVmnrj and http://ideone.com/kxjpQ1. Results are different from your statement.

Comment: Oh yeah. Weird! Same code in my local system had different results!

Answer (score 4):

You should code clear and readable and split in the html and php. The performance profit is not significant...

```
<?php
...
$logo = "img/mainlogo.jpg";
...
?>
...
<img src="<?= $logo ?>" alt="logo"> 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Of the two options you posted, the function is the better choice. But, to be brutally honest, this sort of thing is *exactly* what constants are for:

```
defined('MAIN_LOGO') || define('MAIN_LOGO','img/mainlogo.jpg');
```

suppose you're working on a site that has to support multiple languages, then you can simply use the same trick:

```
defined('CLIENT_LOCALE')  || define('CLIENT_LOCATE',$whereverYouGetThisFrom);
defined('MAIN_LOGO') || define('MAIN_LOGO','img/mainlogo_'.CLIENT_LOCALE.'.jpg');
//if language is EN, mainlogo_EN.jpg will be used, if lang is ES, mainlogo_ES.jpg, etc...
```

Besides, a constant, once defined cannot be redefined (clue is in the name, of course). Also: since PHP still has a lot of C-stuff going under the bonnet, and you've tagged this question `performance`, it might interest you that constants are much like C's macro's, which are a lot faster than regular function calls, or even C++ inline functions (even if they were indeed compiled as inline functions).

Anyway, if you have a ton of these things you want to centralize, either think of creating a couple of `ini` files for your project, and parse them into some sort of global object

Answer (score 1):

`$logo = "img/mainlogo.jpg";` can be redefined naturally later without changing code by doing this `$logo="img/newmainlogo.jpg";` whereas the function would have to be modified itself, in its first definition.

Comment: You mean I couldn't just redefine the contents of the function the same as the variable?

Comment: @Adam, not at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of a function is to avoid code repetition and perform a specific task. Based on that definition, using a function to only return a value is a bad design.

In that context I think is better a good readability in the code than to save several bytes of memory. We are in 2012, optimization is good but this type of micro-optimization is simply ridiculous. I prefer assigning a variable, it's clear and do what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking a list of variables would be cleaner and it does feel like a misuse of functions; overkill or something...